# BigQuery: convert epoch to TIMESTAMP

Tags: google-bigquery, timestamp, epoch

I'm trying to range-join two tables, like so

```
SELECT *
FROM main_table h
INNER JOIN
    test.delay_pairs d
ON
    d.interval_start_time_utc < h.visitStartTime
    AND h.visitStartTime < d.interval_end_time_utc
```

where `h.visitStartTime` is an `INT64` epoch and `d.interval_start_time_utc` and `d.interval_end_time_utc` are proper `TIMESTAMP`s.

The above fails with

```
No matching signature for operator < for argument types: TIMESTAMP, INT64. Supported signature: ANY < ANY
```

Neither wrapping `h.visitStartTime` in `TIMESTAMP()` nor `CAST(d.interval_start_time_utc AS INT64)` work. How do I make the two comparable in BigQuery's Standard SQL dialect?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use [timestamp conversion functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#additional-date-and-timestamp-conversion-functions) like `TIMESTAMP_SECONDS`, `TIMESTAMP_MILLIS`, `TIMESTAMP_MICROS`

for example, assuming your h.visitStartTime is microseconds since the unix epoch

```
SELECT *
FROM main_table h
INNER JOIN test.delay_pairs d
ON d.interval_start_time_utc < TIMESTAMP_MICROS(h.visitStartTime)
AND TIMESTAMP_MICROS(h.visitStartTime) < d.interval_end_time_utc
```

Comment: `visitStartTime` is in seconds since epoch actually (`https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en`) but yeah, that works!

Comment: oh. i haven't realized this is google analytics data :o)

Comment: and the inverse function is `unix_micros` (for my future self)

Answer (score 12):

With **standard** sql you can use one of those, depending on precision:

- `DATE_FROM_UNIX_DATE` - from days epoch to date
- `TIMESTAMP_SECONDS` -  from seconds epoch to timestamp
- `TIMESTAMP_MILLIS` - from milliseconds epoch to timestamp
- `TIMESTAMP_MICROS` - from microseconds epoch to timestamp

See documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#timestamp_seconds

With **legacy** sql you can just use `TIMESTAMP` function and multiply or divide by 1000 to bring it to needed epoch type:

```
SELECT 
  TIMESTAMP(epoch_in_millis / 1000) AS datetime
FROM 
  my_table
```