# Converting timestamp on whole table in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this table which stores millions of rows of data. This data has a date that indicates when was the data entered. I store the data in `NUMERIC` schemas with `EPOCH UNIX` as the format. However, I wanted to convert them to human date (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) and later sort them by date not queried date.

However, it took me so long to find a suitable way. Here's my attempt.

1. I used `SELECT CAST(DATE(timestamp) AS DATE) AS CURR_DT FROM dataset.table` but it gave me this error:

   No matching signature for function DATE for argument types: NUMERIC. Supported signatures: DATE(TIMESTAMP, [STRING]); DATE(DATETIME); DATE(INT64, INT64, INT64) at [1:13]
2. I used this method [BigQuery: convert epoch to TIMESTAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861500/bigquery-convert-epoch-to-timestamp/37863758) but still didn't fully understand

I'm a novice in coding so I hope you guys understand the situation. Thanks!

Comment: What don't you understand about that answer?  It seems to answer your question which makes this a duplicate.  Sorting by date and the Unix epoch is the same thing, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly you would like to take a numeric EPOCH time that is stored as an integer and convert it to a timestamp?
If so you can use the following in BigQuery Standard SQL:

```
select TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(1606048220)
```

It gives the output of:
`2020-11-22 12:30:20 UTC`

[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_seconds)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the date component, then you would convert to a date after converting to a timestamp.  Presumably you have seconds, so you would use `TIMESTAMP_SECONDS()` -- but there are similar functions for milliseconds and microseconds.

For just the date:

```
select date(timestamp_seconds(col))
```

Note that this removes the time component.